# Why $S_4$ has no transitive subgroups of order 6?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

I know that every transitive subgroup of $S_4$  have to be order divisible by 4, but i should solve this **with Galois Theory**. I think this theorem can be usefull:

Theorem 4.2. Let K be afield and f in K[x] a polynomial with Galois group G.

(i) G is isomorphic to a subgroup of some symmetric group $S_n$

(ii)If f is (irreducible) separable of degree n, then n divides \G\ and G is
isomorphic to a transitive subgroup of Sn',

This exercise is from Hungerford, V.4.7.
Thanks

Comment: what? I have to solve this with Galois Theory cause this is an exercise from Galois Group of a Polynomial chapter in Algebra, Hungerford

Answer (score 5):

If $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_n$, then the orbit-stabilizer theorem implies that $G$ has a subgroup of index $n$.

A group of order $6$ does not have a subgroup of index $4$.

Comment: In this course i dont have definition of orbit and stabilizer. I know this is true, i know some demonstrations of this fact, but i need one that uses Galois Theory. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look here

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Symmetric_group_4;_Lattice_of_subgroups_Hasse_diagram.svg

The diagram answers the question, and states the more precise fact that an order $6$ subgroup has to be one of the standard $S_3$'s.